# The fish shell and executing programs from bash through `function`

Tags: bash, executable, fish

I'm currently trying to run the
[atom editor](https://atom.io/)
*in the `bash` shell*, *from the `fish` shell*. It's important that I run `atom` in `bash` because of how ide-haskell handles `ghc-mod` path resolution, and a few other standardization issues.

Here is how I was going at it:

```
#~/.config/fish/config.fish

function start-atom
  bash $HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom $argv
end
```

However, when I try running `start-atom` from `fish`, I get the following error:

```
/home/athan/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom: /home/athan/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom: cannot execute binary file
```

Even though I know this file is correct and executable. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: What's the shebang for `atom`? If it starts with `#!/bin/bash`, it'll be run with bash no matter what.

Comment: ...if, instead, you're relying on functionality added via your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, etc., then you're not going to get that with what you're doing anyhow, since those are only sourced for _interactive_ shells.

Comment: (on a completely different subject -- shell functions and aliases have very different semantics; a function is *not* a subtype of an alias).

Comment: @Charles, in fish, an alias is implemented as a function. `alias foo bar` turns into `function foo; bar $argv; end`

Comment: @glennjackman, that makes an alias a type of function, rather than making a function a type of alias.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you run `bash file_name` it means you're trying to run `file_name` *as a bash script*.

Try this instead:

```
bash -c '$HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom "$@"' dummy $argv
```

The `-c` means "run this *command* with bash" instead of "run this script with bash".

As Charles pointed out in the comments, we have to do a bit of tweaking to pass the parameters to the command.  We pass them to `bash` which will use them as positional parameters inside of the supplied command, hence the `$@`.

Comment: That means the argv given will be passed to the shell, rather than passed to the `atom` script (so the arguments will be in `$@` when `$HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom` is run). Is that really what we want here? I'd think we'd want the argv to be passed to the `atom` script itself.

Comment: ...which, if `atom` has proper executable permissions and shebang such as to make invocation of bash automatic, would just be `$HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom $argv` in fish.

Comment: ...otherwise, it might be something more like `bash -c "$HOME"'/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom "$@"' $argv`, but potentially with some fish-local fixes. (Point being is that if the command passed with `-c` doesn't refer to `$@`, the extra arguments are going to be ignored).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Ah, it looks like I misunderstood the man pages.  It stated `-c string If the -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If there are arguments after the string, they are  assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.`  I assumed it meant the positional parameters of the command, not `bash` itself.

Answer (score 5):

should be: `bash -c '$HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom "$@"' _ $argv`

The underscore will become bash's `$0`

A demo:

```
$ function test_bash_args
      bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' _ $argv
  end
$ test_bash_args one two three
one
two
three
```

If you need that bash session to load your configs, make it a login shell.

So, bottom line: `~/.config/fish/functions/start-atom.fish`

```
function start-atom
    bash -l -c '$HOME/lib/atom/bin/Atom/atom "$@"' _ $argv
end
```